# IIS Redirect Rule doesn't redirect

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

On IIS 7.5 I published several sites. One of these is public and it is reachable at the address www.mysite.com\DGFY. Under this folder i have some applications: DGExpense, DGExpenseAdmin, DGApplication2 ecc. Each of them is reacheable she specific address www.mysite.com\DGFY\DGExpense, www.mysite.com\DGFY\DGExpenseAdmin, ww.mysite.com\DGFY\DGApplication2, ecc

For some reason (out of my control) I need to create another folder in the web site, called www.mysite.com\DGFY2\ and I have to migrate, one by one, these application

Now. I have completed the first one. If I type www.mysite.com\DGFY2\DGExpense, it works. And I deleted DGExpense under the original web site.

But some user still use shortcut to the old path. So i want to create a redirect rule to redirect all request that arrive

This is what I did:

[image: Match Url]

[image: Match Url Test]

[image: Condition]

[image: Test pattern Condition]

[image: Action]

Everything seems ok... but it not works.

If I type [www.mysite.com/DGFY/DGExpense/](http://www.mysite.com/DGFY/DGExpense/) I get 404 Error

What am I doing wrong?

I try also to be more specific with the condition

------------------ EDIT ------------------

Stills struggling with this topic...
I duplicate the virtual machine hosting the site and I activate the failed request log.

IIS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fas2G.png

The Rule:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/elmAV.png

The test:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgW2k.png

The Fail Log.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejAaZ.png

Comment: 1) Use a privacy tab of your browser for testing. 2) Enable FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and learn how to interpret its contents.

Comment: Based on your description, I created the same redirect rule for testing and it was successful. It is recommended that you enable detailed errors in the error page module of IIS and provide us with detailed error information. Also, as LexLi said, you can use FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thanks @LexLi. I do it and I see error  _The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)_

Comment: Thanks @YurongDai. Do you know how to check which path it is looking for?

Comment: As IIS was in its current form for more than a decade, you should be able to use search engines to study previous cases with similar error code. Or you can let a modern AI like Bing Chat or ChatGPT to interpret the key section in FRT for you. People here, however, couldn't see your screen nor help much.

Comment: When you type `www.mysite.com/DGFY/DGExpense` in the browser address bar, will it jump to `www.mysite.com\DGFY2\DGExpense`?

Comment: If you cannot find the key to the error, please enable FRT to track the error page and publish the error log content for community members to help you analyze it. Error log path: `C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles`. Please be careful to hide personal sensitive information.

Comment: Any progress on your issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you!

Comment: Still struggling Stills struggling with this topic...
Some update: I have activated the FailedReq Log and what I see is that at the Pattern Match I have matched: false. Now I try to add some image

Comment: Check the Edit section in the main question